# Xcode - conditional development or production mode

Tags: objective-c, ios, c

In searching for this I could only find info for other languages. I would like to know the best practice for writing conditional statments such as:

```
if (DEV_MODE){
    //do something
}else{
    //do the real stuff
}
```

And then setting DEV_MODE on or off in some global file so I only have to change that to on or off instead of changing code in multiple places. I have some ideas but am looking for advice on the best way to do this.

Comment: Do you want `DEV_MODE` to be determined at compile time?  Or do you want to be able to change `DEV_MODE` at run time without recompiling?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
  // do stuff
#endif
```

The current version of Xcode automatically sets this macro in new projects. Go to your projects Build Settings to make sure. If it's not there you have to add it yourself:

[image]

Comment: Yes, my settings reflect that. So I never have to change anything right? I assume that when I use the AppStore scheme DEBUG will be 0 automatically.

Answer (score 8):

(This question is **not related to Xcode.**)

That said, instead of polluting your code with C-style IFs, you can use preprocessor directives to filter out debug and release mode. As far as I know, it's a common practice to define the `DEBUG` macro to 1 if in testing mode, and not to define it if in release mode. (Also, Xcode may define this for you, I've seen this behavior having been relied upon.) The reason is that the use of the preprocessor is more readable, since it doesn't get into the indentation, it's better separated from the code visually. To sum up, try

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    // do debug stuff here
#else
    // do release stuff here
#endif
```

One extra argument for preprocessor macros is that you can conditionalize the global namespace, which you couldn't within C code. I. e., with preprocessor macros, you can write

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    int functionOne()
    {
    }
#else
    char *functionTwo(int a)
    {
    }
#endif
```

You couldn't do this without the preprocessor.

Answer (score 1):

Preprocessor variables are what you want, in your build configurations define a variable (`DEV_MODE` for example), and then use preprocessor checks like:

```
#if DEV_MODE
    //dev mode code
#else
    //non-dev mode code
#endif
```

Comment: Better to use `DEBUG`, it's defined/undefined by Xcode by default (of course that's not the case using another IDE/a command line toolchain).

Answer (score 0):

In your project settings there is a section called "Preprocessor Macros". In that section you can add a string for your Debug build such as "DEV_MODE" or whatever you want. Then you can do your conditions you listed above and when your app gets built for "Release" or any other setting that does not contain your macro your check should fail.